# Best way to create a profile page PHP/JS/MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Just wondering what would be the best solution to create and store user details for a profile page. 
Quick example, lets say user can select multiple languages he/she can speak. How should I store them in mysql database? Another one would be work experience and education.

General idea would be that there are three types of user: admin, nanny and a family. Admin is general and don't need any personal informatsion regarding the other two categories. 
Nanny and family have almost identical options, work experience, location, etc.

If I store all the values in one field (lets say languages), would that affect searching by this column?

Right now I have user table only since I don't know how to proceed. 
Cheers and thanks in advance.

Comment: you might need a query like `SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id = $userid`. Anyways, SO is here to help you, not to do the whole work for you. You should show what you have done so far.

Comment: There are many tutorials available online for using a database in PHP.  We can certainly help when you get stuck somewhere or have a specific question, but Stack Overflow doesn't seek to replace the many end-to-end tutorials already available.  Start with some of those.

Comment: I know how to use mysql and that. Just some general thought how to start with something like that. Since english is not my native I find it pretty hard to search as well. 'If I can explain it then my question was how to store multiple items from a select box for example.

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to put your database in 3rd Normal Form. [Tutorial here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/third-normal-form.htm)

It's all about only storing things once, and then using foreign keys when you want to reference duplicate data. You would need a table called `user_types` which contains records that have ID numbers that you reference in your `users` table.

It's okay to put fields in your `users` table that won't be used by every user, they just need to be optional fields.